# Spark History Server throws Stream is corrupted error

Tags: apache-spark

When I try to open some of applications in Spark History Server it shows error, but it happens not for all applications, even not for every run of the same app run:

```
HTTP ERROR 500 java.io.IOException: Stream is corrupted
URI:    /history/spark-964ffa883c3c4ba8b7d7f06873f68c1d/jobs/
STATUS: 500
MESSAGE:    java.io.IOException: Stream is corrupted
SERVLET:    org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer$$anon$1-4d1ff6b1
CAUSED BY:  java.io.IOException: Stream is corrupted
Caused by:
java.io.IOException: Stream is corrupted
    at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockInputStream.refill(LZ4BlockInputStream.java:200)
    at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockInputStream.read(LZ4BlockInputStream.java:157)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:181)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:326)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:392)
    at scala.io.BufferedSource$BufferedLineIterator.hasNext(BufferedSource.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$20.hasNext(Iterator.scala:884)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:511)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ReplayListenerBus.replay(ReplayListenerBus.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ReplayListenerBus.replay(ReplayListenerBus.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.$anonfun$parseAppEventLogs$3(FsHistoryProvider.scala:1122)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.$anonfun$parseAppEventLogs$3$adapted(FsHistoryProvider.scala:1120)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2611)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.$anonfun$parseAppEventLogs$1(FsHistoryProvider.scala:1120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.$anonfun$parseAppEventLogs$1$adapted(FsHistoryProvider.scala:1118)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.parseAppEventLogs(FsHistoryProvider.scala:1118)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.rebuildAppStore(FsHistoryProvider.scala:1099)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.createInMemoryStore(FsHistoryProvider.scala:1337)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.getAppUI(FsHistoryProvider.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer.getAppUI(HistoryServer.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.ApplicationCache.$anonfun$loadApplicationEntry$2(ApplicationCache.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.ApplicationCache.time(ApplicationCache.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.ApplicationCache.org$apache$spark$deploy$history$ApplicationCache$$loadApplicationEntry(ApplicationCache.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.ApplicationCache$$anon$1.load(ApplicationCache.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.ApplicationCache$$anon$1.load(ApplicationCache.scala:52)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4004)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4874)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.ApplicationCache.get(ApplicationCache.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.ApplicationCache.withSparkUI(ApplicationCache.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer.org$apache$spark$deploy$history$HistoryServer$$loadAppUi(HistoryServer.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer$$anon$1.doGet(HistoryServer.scala:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:503)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:791)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.HttpSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpSecurityFilter.scala:95)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:766)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:234)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Any thougs what could be a reason of this?

SparkHS version is 3.1.1